# Setting a gradient background to a button automatically resizes it

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to set a gradient xml file as background to a button.But when i add the drawable xml file as background, the size of the button changes.The button is to the right of edittext and the size of the button becomes bigger than the edittext.

The code:

The button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btndob"
            android:layout_width="127dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/button_clicked_selector"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="SELECT DATE" />
```

button_clicked_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient" /> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_clicked_gradient" /> 
</selector>
```

button_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#00aff0"
      android:endColor="#0081b0"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

button_clicked_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#00aff0"
      android:endColor="#00aff0"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Comment: change the button android:layout_height="fill_parent"  to  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: @balajikoduri changing it to wrapcontent decreases the size of the button further.

Comment: keep in mind that the default background has some padding, and it's being removed when you override it. So the change of size might be just due to your background's lack of padding. To be sure, you can inspect the default background of your current theme.

Comment: @AlvarezAriel But i am not using a static image as background.I am using start and end colors in hexcode inside an xml file.

Comment: wrapcontent means it will strech the button with respect to your dependencies, like"alignparentright=true and to right of edittext"

Comment: Could you show us a screenshot of the issue? And a complete layout example if possible (instead of the <button .../> alone ).